# Publishing gems on RubyGems and/or on Homebrew?

Tags: rubygems, homebrew

`git-pulls` is the first gem I maintain and I am responsible for which is used by real people other than me. That brings me to situation I never have been confronted to.

For example, someone ask for the creation of a brew package [here](https://github.com/schacon/git-pulls/issues/15). To what [someone answered](https://github.com/schacon/git-pulls/issues/15#issuecomment-753502):

> Homebrew specifically doesn't want to replace systems like Rubygems, since it would only lead to duplication.

Hovewer, I found [this entry](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/6#page19) on the RubyGems documentation which explains how to distribute gems both on RubyGems and Homebrew.

The issue was created a couple of years ago. And I have no clue wether the RubyGems community opinion evolved since. And I do not find answer for this.

I have no position for this right now, so as a rookie gem publisher, I look for insightful tips :)

So, duplication or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby gems are generally not accepted into Homebrew; rather, it is expected that users will install Ruby (possibly via Homebrew), and then install/manage gems with RubyGems instead.

Comment: OK, thanks. Any source about this or is it just some kind of habits?

Comment: @AdrienGiboire: This page (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Acceptable-Formula) sort of touches on it, but it's more a decision that's been discussed on the mailing list and other venues.